# Show that A is unitary

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to show that $S+i(I-S^2)^{1/2}$, where $S$ is a self adjoint matrix of norm $\leq 1$, is unitary. I have already checked that $I-S^2$ is positive. I am aware that I need to use the Stone-Weierstrass theorem somehow - something about expressing $(I-S^2)^{1/2}$ as a limit of polynomials but I don't really have a clue where to start.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is $S$ here?

Comment: Sorry, $S$ is a self adjoint matrix with norm $\leq 1.$

Comment: Looks like a part of the proof that each matrix is a linear combination of four unitaries :-)

Comment: Will look into this, thanks!

Comment: @TomekKania: Yeah thought so too ^^ ...are you aware of that, maths1234?

Comment: I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: struggling still with this - is there anywhere I can find the proof of the four unitaries??

Comment: Take a matrix $A$. Without loss of generality $\|A\|\leqslant 1$. Write $A$ as a linear combination of two self-adjoint matrices and apply the above to these two matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $S$ is hermitian we have that
$$
A=S+i(I-S^2)^{1/2}\,\,\Longrightarrow\,\,A^*=S-i(I-S^2)^{1/2},
$$
and hence
$$
A^*A=\big(S-i(I-S^2)^{1/2}\big)\big(S+i(I-S^2)^{1/2}\big)=S^2+(1-S^2)=I,
$$
as $S(I-S^2)^{1/2}=(I-S^2)^{1/2}S$, which means that $A$ is unitary.

Comment: S is not Hermitian unfortunately.

Comment: or maybe it is... how would i show that S is hermitian?